# Creating indexed view that compiles automatically on certain time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In Oracle database the materialized views can be created that can automatically be refreshed at certain time interval. How can this be implemented in SQL Server using indexed views or other technique?
The underlying table being very large and the change in base table is very often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, an Indexed View will always return current results.  Updates need not be scheduled because the DBMS will automatically refresh the view if underlying data changes.

If you don't want to incur the overhead of maintaining the indexed view, you can drop it while not needed and then re-create before you will use it (e.g. before daily / weekly / monthly reporting runs).

Comment: what if the underlying table is very huge

Comment: Benchmark the indexed view creation overhead and time.  Periodic updates that Oracle allows are certainly more flexible than the options that MSSQL offer (always incur a little overhead to keep the indexed view current, or periodically incur full overhead to re-create as needed).  MSSQL just doesn't offer the option to incrementally incur a fraction of the overhead to update the indexed view periodically.  If you really need that, one option is to use a table that you update yourself periodically, e.g. by scheduling a stored procedure.

Comment: Let me try with that Thank you very much for helping :)

Comment: @EricJ. can the Indexed View be created such that it is not updated when the underlying table changes? I will simply re-create the Indexed View every night. That way there will be no overhead associated when new data is inserted in the table? I need this feature to optimize one of my View.

Comment: @HammadKhan I don't think so, but what you're describing is really a (temporary) table representing your data at a point in time, e.g. as illustrated here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114441/how-to-create-table-using-select-query-in-sql-server

Comment: @EricJ. thanks for the response. Yes table would solve that problem but I thought Indexed View is a more elegant way to tackle it. I will think over table implementation. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieved using a combination of a script and a SQL Server agent job. Once you script out your re-organize/re-build operation on the index, you can use the same script to plug into the SQL Server Agent job to run on a schedule.

The other option would be to look at the database maintenance plan. Depending on the size of your underlying table, you can try to create partitioned indexes so that index maintenance becomes a lil bit easier.