# How to create table using select query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I try to make 50-100 tables using SYS queries

```
SELECT windows_release, windows_service_pack_level, 
       windows_sku, os_language_version
FROM sys.dm_os_windows_info OPTION (RECOMPILE);     -- DEĞİŞİRSE INSERT ETSIN AYNI ISE DEĞİŞMESİN

-- Gives you major OS version, Service Pack, Edition, and language info for the operating system

-- SQL Server Services information (SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 or greater)
SELECT servicename, startup_type_desc, status_desc, 
last_startup_time, service_account, is_clustered, cluster_nodename
FROM sys.dm_server_services OPTION (RECOMPILE);


-- Hardware information from SQL Server 2008 
-- (Cannot distinguish between HT and multi-core)
SELECT cpu_count AS [Logical CPU Count], hyperthread_ratio AS [Hyperthread Ratio],
cpu_count/hyperthread_ratio AS [Physical CPU Count], 
physical_memory_in_bytes/1048576 AS [Physical Memory (MB)], 
sqlserver_start_time --, affinity_type_desc -- (affinity_type_desc is only in 2008 R2)
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

How to create table from SYS tables queries result?

Comment: Don't create a table per server. Create one table which has server as a column in it and put all the info in there, marked against the server

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An example statement that uses a sub-select :

```
select * into MyNewTable
from
(
select 
  * 
from 
[SomeOtherTablename]
where 
  EventStartDatetime >= '01/JAN/2018' 
)
) mysourcedata
;
```

note that the sub query must be given a name .. any name .. e.g. above example gives the subquery a name of mysourcedata.  Without this a syntax error is issued in SQL*server 2012.

The database should reply with a message like:
(9999 row(s) affected)

Comment: Accepted answer should be the one below : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11114484/6515775

Comment: this accepted answer example shows the requirement to give an alias name to the sub-select is more useful than the answer below which doesn't give indication that an alias name is required and will leave a person wondering why they are getting error message about incorrect syntax? I'd still vote for this accepted answer as being something some can immediately make use of.

Comment: Providing an alias for the sub-query worked for me! Special thanks for the explanation you added in your answer related to the alias requirement.

Comment: Downvoted because of the pointless sub query: if you have `SELECT * FROM x WHERE y` and you want it in a new table Z you just add an `INTO z` before the from:  `SELECT * INTO z FROM x WHERE y`. You **don’t need to** wrap the whole thing in a sub query just to do an INTO:  `/*no*/SELECT * INTO z FROM (SELECT * FROM x WHERE y)a`

Comment: Using a sub query was basis of the question ... i.e. wanting to create a table based on a complex sub query .. so no, not pointless !

Answer (score 81):

```
select <column list> into <table name> from <source> where <whereclause>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer :-)
It works in SQL Sever, unlike the one that is accepted now (and has -1 score btw)

Comment: The accepted one seems to be more or less valid in SQL Data Warehouse, which is on the Microsoft platform, but still not in SQL Server or Azure SQL >:( 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-ctas

Comment: if <source> here is a subquery in brackets, then it needs to be given an alias name as per the accepted answer of this question, otherwise you will get message like:    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near ')'.     Hope this helps ...

Comment: I see absolute tons of answers like this on the internet, and all I get is error `Undeclared variable`.

Answer (score 15):

```
select <column list> into <dest. table> from <source table>;
```

You could do this way.

```
SELECT windows_release, windows_service_pack_level, 
       windows_sku, os_language_version
into   new_table_name
FROM   sys.dm_os_windows_info OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

You can use Import data ( you need a dba privileges)

The database name that you want to create table on -> right mouse click -> Tasks -> Import Data -> Source & Destination informations -> write query(second option) -> paste your query.

This will create a table on destination

Answer (score 0):

To create a new table based on a dynamic SQL query:

```sql
select * 
into dbo.new_table 
from (
  select * from dbo.table_a a
  inner join dbo.table_b b on a.id = b.id) as source_query;
```

The downside of the `from {table}` syntax is that it only allows retrieving data from a single table, which is often not meeting the need.