# Create permanent table based on temporary table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a temp table which aggregates columns from multiple tables.

I would like to convert this temp table into a permanent table without explicit specifying the column names and their types.

Don't know if i have explained this well enough

Comment: Seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683758/how-to-create-a-table-from-select-query-result-in-sql-server-2008 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114441/how-to-create-table-using-select-query-in-sql-server

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `SELECT ... INTO`:

```
SELECT *
INTO dbo.normal_table
FROM #temp_table
-- WHERE 1 = 2;   --add if you only want table structure and not actual data
```

Things to check after table creation:

- `IDENTITY` column and current value (may need reseeding)
- `DEFAULT` values of column(if temp table has defaults, normal table  needs to be `ALTER`ed)
- `COLLATION` tempdb may have different collation than your database
- size of columns, precision and scale (`VARCHAR`,`NVARCHAR`,`CHAR`, `DECIMAL`..) if `SELECT` contains expressions

If temp table does not contain `IDENTITY` column you can add one using:

```
SELECT ID  = IDENTITY(INT,1,1)
     ,col1 = NULL   -- NULL by default are treated as INT so you may need casting
     ,col2 = CAST(NULL AS DECIMAL(38,10))
     ,t.*
INTO dbo.table_name
FROM #temp t
```

Comment: This gives error: There is already an object named 'table_name' in the database.