# SELECT INTO in SQL Server vs Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Something like this would generally work in Oracle, but I'm having problem adjusting it to work on SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE mynewtbl AS  
( 
  with 
  a as (select col1, col2, col3 from table1),
  b as (select col4, col5, col6 from table2)
  select col1, col4, col6
)
```

I know that I should be using a `SELECT INTO` statement but, it's not working.

This is the error that I'm getting:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'

Please help

Comment: what are you expecting the result to look like? as someone who knows SQL Server, but not Oracle, it's not clear what you're trying to achieve; the code you've presented doesn't contain `into`...

Comment: Please add your sql code.

Comment: I have a huge query full of withs and union alls.  I need to create a table out of it. In oracle this would be easy, just create table as (...), but i'm having trouble doing it on sql server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create table using select query in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114441/how-to-create-table-using-select-query-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

The code in SQL Server would look like this:

```
with a as (
      select col1, col2, col3 from table1
     ),
     b as (
      select col4, col5, col6 from table2
     )
select col1, col4, col6
into mynewtbl
from . . .;
```

You need a `from` clause regardless of the database.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you want something like...

```
; with
    a as ( select col1, col2, col3 from table1),
    b as ( select col4, col5, col6 from table2)
select col1, col4, col6
into mynewtbl
from a, b
```

(not syntactically valid cte, I think, but just for illustration)

Assuming you have a `SELECT` working, you should just be able to drop the `INTO x` immediately before your `FROM` clause.

- [SQL Server `SELECT` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql)

If you have a `SELECT` query that works (returns all the data you want in the table), and you're experiencing issues because of some of UNIONs, etc, then wrapping that as a subquery should resolve the issue -- keeping any CTE's at the top.

So instead of

```
SELECT a FROM table1
UNION
SELECT b FROM table2
```

You have

```
SELECT *
INTO mytable
FROM (
    SELECT a FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT b FROM table2
) results
```

Comment: Problem is that i am having unions. This is the error I get:

SELECT INTO must be the first query in a statement containing a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. It seems that there is a problem with FROM and WITH keywords. 
Error:

    Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: you should still have your CTE's at the top of the query, and then reference them in the subselect.