# How do I resolve this error on the select keyword

Tags: sql-server

I wanted to create a new table from an existing table however, at present, I get an error on the `SELECT` keyword, I've tried aliasing it but that didn't work.

I've tried aliasing it and checking the columns to see if I had misspelt anything or if I was calling the correct database or not and everything seems to be in order.

SQL:

```
create table testTable as 
select CompanyName as customer_companyname
, contactname 
from Customers;
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

Comment: I can't read that tiny image text on my small laptop screen. Can't you copy-and-paste it as text instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114441/how-to-create-table-using-select-query-in-sql-server

Comment: I think what you're trying to create is called a `view`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create a table via `create table ... select ...` syntax.

You can use `select ... into ...` to create a table with a similar schema to the source table, containing the selected data; but it won't be identical to the original table (e.g. things like keys will be missing).  [Select Into Docs](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp)

Or you can use a [Create Table ...](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp) statement with a suitable definition to create the table, followed by [Insert Into ...](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) to populate the data in that table.

Comment: @siggemannen actually that's not at all required, votes are anonymous for a reason. When you hover your mouse over the downvote option you can see the reasons.